# iptables string not dropping packet from tcp streams while using conntrack and string

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp

I'm facing an unusual issue where specific TCP steams are not getting dropped by iptables; instead it's like iptables is just removing those specific packets.

We're getting the following traffic:

```
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_wCsFbzYvU4RoBXK6fFpOyk7gT3cCl8 HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_orvy148BFILOSVYbeilptwz2BEHLOR HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_uqIxPsKm2UxPs7Z2UjCeuM2HjzRg9O HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_HKMPRTWYadfhkmpsuxz1368ADFIKMP HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_JKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMM HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_8CJMQTXaehkoswz37AEHKOSVZchlpt HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_KRYfmu18FMSZgov29FMTahpw39GNUb HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_y26AEIMQUYcgkptx159DHLPTXbfjos HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_HHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJ HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:16 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_CCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEE HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
```

We've tried to block it with:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 80 -m string --string ".*CtrlFunc_.*" --algo bm -j DROP
```

and:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 80  -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED --ctstatus EXPECTED,ASSURED,CONFIRMED,NONE -m string --string "CtrlFunc_" --algo bm -j DROP
```

However what occurs is the following:

```
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:34 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:34 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:34 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:34 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:35 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:35 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:35 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:35 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [27/Jul/2013:11:52:35 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 380 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
```

Is it possible to block TCP based streams with iptables?

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the subtleties with using a flow based packet filter.

If you use target `-j REJECT` then a `RST` packet will be sent back, terminating the connection.